# "boroughs" vs. "districts"

Tags: word-usage

Google and some other guys use "boroughs" when talking about the administrative divisions of NYC:

[image]

keywords: how many boroughs in nyc

Whereas [some post](http://www.ilovenewyork.se/nyc_facts_districts_en.asp) uses "districts" when talking about the administrative divisions of NYC:

[image]

Google uses "districts" when talking about the administrative divisions of Beijing:

[image]

keywords: how many boroughs in Beijing

Why is that?

[A post says](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskUK/comments/1u3g0u/what_are_the_differences_between_districts_and/)

> In general a district is any subdivision of a county, and a **borough** is just a district which has been granted permission to call itself a borough and call the leader of the council a mayor. It's similar to the way that a city is just a town that has been given permission to call itself a city.

However, those 16 districts of Beijing has been granted permission, why people don't use "borough" there?

Comment: Great question! I think most people use boroughs for NYC, and districts for elsewhere, but I’m not a New Yorker, so don’t take this as gospel.

Comment: Probably because the term _borough_ is specific to English-speaking countries. It originally meant a fortified town. There is no historic reason to use it when speaking of districts in China. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borough

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beijing hasn't been divided into districts or boroughs, it is divided into 区 (Qū)

Now as your source notes, a "borough" is just a district that is called (in the local language) "borough".  In the same way that a "county" is a district that has the title "county" and "city" is a town that has the title "city".  These titles can be defined legally or beaurcratically, or may just exist by tradition.

For Beijing, the districts are called "区" and that is legal, or bureaucratic title.
This might be translated as "district" or "borough" or some other term, according to local tradition. The tradition in China is to translate 区 as "district".  On the other hand in Japan, "区" (ku) is translated as "city". or "ward" and never "district" or "borough" (even though it refers to a subdivision of Tokyo)

It is just a translator's convention, established by tradition.  In translating language that are close to English, there is often a cognate that can be used: The départament in France can be translated as "departments" in English (even though they are somewhat similar to counties)  You can't do that for Chinese. So translators have come up with conventional translations.  And the conventional translation of 区 is district.

Comment: Interestingly, in Japan those 区 are categorized as wards, especially in the case of special wards of Tokyo, but their proper English translation always includes "city". It's created a lot of confusion. "Chiyoda City? Where is that? What, in Tokyo?" The official Japanese convention translates 郡 (gun) as district. The greater Tokyo area has one district, Nishi-Tama District.

Comment: But everything gets extremely muddled in writing, because more often than not people don't follow this to a T. Just look at some examples from Wikipedia: "Notable **districts** of Tokyo include Chiyoda, Shinjuku, and Shibuya." "While falling under the jurisdiction of Tokyo Metropolitan Government, each ward is also a **borough** with its own elected leader and council, like other cities of Japan."

Comment: Sure nobody has to follow a convention.  Its just a convention.  There is no law that says you have to use district for the subdivisions of Beijing.  Please feel free to use borough or city or ward (or department, prefecture, mayoralty, or any other word that you think fits.)

Comment: I have never seen mayoralty used in this sense. To me it means the office or the tenure of a mayor.

Comment: no,  Actually I just made that word up,  didn't know it was a "real" word.